# Copy JS file and parse it to JSON file using webpack

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, copy-webpack-plugin

I need to copy and parse JS file with js object to JSON file using webpack. Is there any simple soluition for that, like plugin or something. I thinking to use CopyWebpackPlugin but I have no idea how to parse files to JSON
[image: img]